# charts Treemap with ggplots and treemapify

Tags: r, ggplot2, treemap

I have simple data frame that I want to visualize with a treemap. I've made using `ggplot` and `treemapify`. It seems ok, but I am wondering how can I show both name and lab variables inside the treemap without showing one as a label and one in the legend .

Here is dummay sample and my try:

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(treemapify)

 data <-
   data.frame(
     name = c("Group A", "Group B", "Group C", "Group D"),
     value = c(8, 22, 66, 4),
     lab = c("8%", "22%", "66%", "4%")
   ) %>%
   mutate(lab = as.factor(lab))



 ggplot(data, aes(area = value, fill = lab,  label = name)) +
   geom_treemap() +
   geom_treemap_text(
     colour = "white",
     place = "centre",
     size = 15,
   ) +
   scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greens")
```

The treemap graph :
[image]

I am trying to have a graph like this example
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can concatenate the lab and name and specify it as the label inside aes:

```
ggplot(data, 
aes(area = value, fill = lab,label = paste(name,lab,sep="\n"))) +
   geom_treemap() +
   geom_treemap_text(
     colour = "white",
     place = "centre",
     size = 15)+
   scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greens")
```

If you would like to specify the order of the palette, for example darkest green goes to 66%, specify the levels of the lab in data, for example:

```
data$lab = factor(data$lab,levels=c("4%", "8%", "22%", "66%"))
# and plot
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks men, May I ask another question , how to force the order of a color palette in treemap ?

Comment: sure thing. you would like 4% to be the lightest and 66% to be darkest?

Comment: Yes, something like that

Comment: I have edited my answer, see if it's what you wanted?